# PNG in IE 8 with jquery displays as a grey colour

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, png

Im trying to find a solution to this horrible grey png on hover (which is meant to be a transparent yellow, it only seems to display like this in IE. nothing i try seems to work. any help or hints would be really handy.

this is the jquery.

```
    $('#header').hover(
function() {
$("#slideshow_bg").stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "fast");
},
function() {
$("#slideshow_bg").stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");


});
});
```

This is the html

```
<div id="header">



    <div id="ql_container" > 
        <span class="qltext">Our Systems</span>

            <div id="slidetabs">
                <a href="#">Therm Masonry</a>
                <a href="#">Concrete Block</a>
                <a href="#c">Precast Concrete</a>

            </div>

    </div>

    <!-- container for the slides -->
    <div class="images" style="float:left;">

        <!-- first slide -->
          <div class="slides" style="display:; position:absolute; background-image:url(03_building/02_concrete_block/02_IMAGES/02_HeroShot_1.jpg); width:779px; height:448px;" />
        <div id="slideshow_bg" style="opacity:;">

             <h2>lorem ipsum</H2>
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam volutpat mauris in dolor egestas id iaculis tortor dignissim. Duis auctor dui vitae augue viverra pretium. Vestibulum ullamcorper iaculis tincidunt.</p>
             <p><a href="#"> Specifications</a> | <a href="#">Details</a></p>

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

this is the css

```
#slideshow_bg{
opacity : 0;
/* IE 8 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
/* IE 5-7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
zoom:1;
width:170px;
height:398px;
padding:25px 20px 25px 20px; 
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
background-image:url(../../images/slidesshow_desc_bg.png);
_background:none;
_filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../../images/slidesshow_desc_bg.png',sizingMethod='crop');
}
```

I know this probably looks pretty messy but,,
any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your div with class slides. There is a problem with the display attribute. It has to be like this:

```
<div class="slides" style="position:absolute; 
    background-image:url(03_building/02_concrete_block/02_IMAGES/02_HeroShot_1.jpg);     
    width:779px; height:448px;" />
```

Or you give a value to your display attribute.

Same for this div:

```
<div id="slideshow_bg" style="opacity:;">
```

Hope this will fix your problem. Let me know.

Comment: thanks for the help, i went for rgba in the end, but now the text seems to sit behind that

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the z-index. You can put elements in layers with this.

[Click here for some info about z-index](http://www.quackit.com/css/properties/css_z-index.cfm)